# Have dynamic datetime showing in Google Slides

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

Is there a way to insert the dynamic date and/or time in Google Slides?

I seem to have issues forgetting updating the same (usually the month) when I make presentations.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for dynamically update or put the value in the Slide, yet. So as a workaround, for example, how about updating the value by running a script at the custom menu? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: If you need regular updates without user action, then the script solution with time-driven triggers is the best. If more complex user action is desired, then you may include some UI elements for manual run such as menu items, dialogs or sidebars.

Comment: Duplicate of this question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92908/inserting-field-for-current-date-time-in-google-slides, whose responses include sample script.